# Publishing web service using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.0, qgis-server

I want to show different types of surveyed land parcels which are available in  shapefile format, in our country map.  That map will be published in a web site and it will be available for surveyors.

I am using QGIS version 2.18.9 and PostgreSQL database. Can I do this using QGIS or should I use QGIS server version?

Comment: Don't forget to  to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: I suggest either qgis2web or Qgis Cloud, depending on the user interface you want to provide.